# Timer_Tick not Working properly in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, label

I have this program where in after 2 seconds it will refresh and check if there is/ are changes in database. If yes then it will refresh the data shown.

Here's my code

in my page load have this code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Timer1.Enabled = true;
        Timer1.Interval = 2000;
        Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Timer1_Tick);
    }
```

and in my Timer1_Tick

```
 private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select w_id, cq_num from [dbo].[WindowTeller] where w_stat = 1 ", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            w_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            cq_num = reader.GetInt32(1);


            if (w_id == 1)
            {

                if (cqnum1 != cq_num) //compare old value of queue number to present value 
                {
                    lblTeller1.Text = w_id.ToString();
                    lblTeller1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                    if (cq_num == 0)
                    {
                        lblQueueNumber1.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Prefix1.Text = prefix;


                        if (cq_num.ToString().Length == 1)
                        {

                            lblQueueNumber1.Text = "00" + cq_num.ToString();
                        }

                        else if (cq_num.ToString().Length == 2)
                        {

                            lblQueueNumber1.Text = "0" + cq_num.ToString();
                        }

                        else if (cq_num.ToString().Length == 3)
                        {

                            lblQueueNumber1.Text = cq_num.ToString();
                        }

                        lblQueueNumber1.CssClass = "blink";
                        //[END][ADD]
                        Prefix1.CssClass = "blink";

                        providesound();

                        cqnum1 = cq_num;

                    }



                }

                else
                {
                    //[START][ADD]<H2_valoramaelagarnia || 4/10/2014 ||Remove Blinking >
                    lblQueueNumber1.CssClass = "";
                    Prefix1.CssClass = "";

                }


            }
            else if (w_id == 2)
            {
                if (cqnum2 != cq_num)
                {


                    lblTeller2.Text = w_id.ToString();
                    lblTeller2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    if (cq_num == 0)
                    {
                        lblQueueNumber2.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Prefix2.Text = prefix;

                        if (cq_num.ToString().Length == 1)
                        {

                            lblQueueNumber2.Text = "00" + cq_num.ToString();
                        }

                        else if (cq_num.ToString().Length == 2)
                        {

                            lblQueueNumber2.Text = "0" + cq_num.ToString();
                        }

                        else if (cq_num.ToString().Length == 3)
                        {

                            lblQueueNumber2.Text = cq_num.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    lblQueueNumber2.CssClass = "blink";

                    Prefix2.CssClass = "blink";
                    providesound();


                    cqnum2 = cq_num;

                }
                else
                {

                    lblQueueNumber2.CssClass = "";

                    Prefix2.CssClass = "";
                }

            }

        }


        con.Close();

        con.Open();



        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select w_id, cq_num from [dbo].[WindowTeller] where w_stat = 0", con);
        SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader2.Read())
        {
            w_id = reader2.GetInt32(0);
            cq_num = reader2.GetInt32(1);
            if (w_id == 1)
            {
                lblTeller1.Text = w_id.ToString();
                lblTeller1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                lblQueueNumber1.Text = "";
                Prefix1.Text = "";
            }
            else if (w_id == 2)
            {
                lblTeller2.Text = w_id.ToString();
                lblTeller2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                lblQueueNumber2.Text = "";
                Prefix2.Text = "";
            }

        }

        con.Close();

        return;

    }
```

What will happen here is that when the status of the window is = 0 the text color will change into gray and when it's status = 1 it will turn to red.

the problem now is after 2 seconds, the label doesn't change it's color into red when status = 1. But when I change it to 0 it changes into gray immediately.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: add if(!ispostback) condition in your form_Load event